# Maven and LifecycleExecutionException

Tags: maven

I want to modelize the following 3 projects with Maven :

- parent project `A`
- 2 modules `B` and `C`
- `B`->`C` and `C`->`B`

I tested 3 things :

1. create dependencies `B` and `C` in `A`
2. create dependency `B` in `C` and `C` in `B`
3. idem 2 and adding exclusion of `B` inside `B` project coming from `C` dependency and exclusion of `C` inside `C` project coming from `B` dependency.

All give me `LifecycleExecutionException`.

So is there a way to modelize this please ?

I hope that the only way isn't to merge `B` and `C` inside one unique project...

Comment: Why are b and c both dependent on each other?  Seems like a hard thing to justify, and it could be the source of your troubles as well.

Comment: hi, I simplify the situation. I have nearly 10 projects (entities, web, ejb-client, ejb-impl, dtos etc...). Necessarily, inter-dependencies appear...I'm just wondering if Maven knows how to handle that or if we have to "mix" all inside max 2-3 projects...? Thx

Comment: Could we have some more error information than just `LifecycleExectionException`?

Comment: it's just because B needs C to compile and C needs B to compile (cycle reference). I will refactor my project and merge B and C